# Exponent of 3D array with numpy

Tags: numpy, vectorization, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

Given a NxMxM array containing N, MxM square arrays, how do I calculate the N exponents of the MxM arrays.

```
from scipy.linalg import expm
U = np.random.rand(10,6,6) #Given 10 six by six arrays calculate the following:
exp = expm(U)
>>> [expm(U[0]),expm(U[1])...expm(U[9])]
```

I would like to avoid for loops and use numpy manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
exp = [expm(x) for x in U]
```

Since `expm` accepts only a single square matrix the loop over matrices will run Python. But since the matrices are anyway to be dealt with independently this shouldn't be much of an issue.